# When should I handle exceptions and when should they be thrown?

Tags: c#, exception

When programming, I find myself having a hard time thinking about how my program should work, when an *exception could be thrown*.

Take the following example:

```
    public void AddComponent(IEntityComponent component)
    {
        if (component == null)
        {
            // Should I throw an ArgumentNullException or should I just return?
        }

        if (ContainsComponentOfType(component.GetType()))
        {
            // Should I return here? Or should I throw an ArgumentException?
        }

        // Finally, we know we can add the component to the entity
        components.Add(component);
    }

    public bool ContainsComponentOfType(Type componentType)
    {
        if (componentType == null)
        {
            // Should I throw an exception here? Should I return false?
        }

        return components.Any(c => c.GetType() == componentType);
    }
```

Note that the above code will be used by people creating a game with my engine.

Comment: In the given case _I_ think you should throw. The consumers of your API surely made a mistake when they passed `null` here, and by simply returning you would hide that error from them. But as it stands the question is really opinion based, which makes it off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: This seems rather opinion based. From *my* perspective as a developer: if I use a library, I want to have feedback about what happened/happens. If I call `AddComponent` with a null reference and don't see any difference to calling it with a correct value, I'd be confused. Usually, throwing when something is not as it should be is a *good thing*. If you want to avoid that, maybe you could have a `bool TryAddComponent` that returns false instead of throwing... but again, opinions on this are likely to differ.

Comment: You should only throw an exception when it is impossible for your code to meaningfully continue. It's the "throw your hands in the air" response. It's like if you're asked to divide by zero or you run out of hard drive space. If someone tries to add a `null` then probably that's an exception. If someone asks if a collection contains a `null` then that's just a `false`. You decide that, but be consistent. Just remember that exceptions are expensive, so avoid the cost where possible.

Comment: Btw.: `components.Any(c => c.GetType() == componentType)` is O(n). I don't know what else you're using `components` for, but if the order of items doesn't matter, then you might want to have it as `Dictionary<Type, IEntityComponent>`. Checking for type would be `components.ContainsKey(componentType)`, which is basically O(1).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe *why* you're having a hard time deciding. What specifically are the pros/cons that you're struggling with? As your question stands now, I believe it's too broad/opinion-based. But it's very common to just throw an exception if the client passes you invalid arguments. Methods that bend over backwards to try to "do the right thing" with invalid arguments often end up producing bugs later on down the line which are very hard to trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The policy can *vary* from zero tolerance (throwing exceptions at any point where they can be thrown) to lenient (where we forgive caller as far as we can do).
The common practice is `DoAction` (`AddComponent` in your case) be strict and `TryDoAction` (`TryAddComponent`) be lenient.

Zero tolerance version:

```
// Strict: we are quite sure in the arguments; 
// that's why it's an exceptional case (error in the code!) if arguments are invalid
// and we fail to add 
public void AddComponent(IEntityComponent component) {
  // Contract: here we validate the input arguments
  // Since we sure in them we apply zero tolerance policy:
  // if contract is't met throw corresponding exception

  // we want not null component  
  if (component == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(component));

  // which contains at least one item of the required type
  if (ContainsComponentOfType(component.GetType()))
    throw new ArgumentException("Component must contain...",  nameof(component)); 

  // Finally, we know we can add the component to the entity
  components.Add(component);
}
```

Lenient implementation

```
// Lenient: we have arguments from the (unknown) source in which we are not sure
// we want just to try adding (and get true / false) if we succeed or not
public bool TryAddComponent(IEntityComponent component) {
  // Contract: we validate the input arguments from unknown source
  // if validation fails we should not throw any exception (it's not an
  // exceptional case to get incorrect data from unreliable source) but
  // let the caller know that we don't succeed

  // We can't add if component is null
  if (component == null)
    return false;

  // We have nothing to add if component doesn't contain required items 
  if (ContainsComponentOfType(component.GetType()))
    return false;

  // Finally, we know we can add the component to the entity
  components.Add(component);

  return true;
}

// Do we really want to expose it?
// ContainsComponentOfType is an implementation detail which we keep private
private bool ContainsComponentOfType(Type componentType) {
  // Since it's a private method we can omit the check
  return components.Any(c => c.GetType() == componentType);
}
```

Usage: since you are building an *engine* both cases (strict and lenient) can appear

```
MyClass loader = new MyClass();

...

// Cloud Database must not be corrupted; if it is, we want to know it immediatly
loader.AddComponent(componentFromCloud);

...

// Local file can contain any data: it can be corrupted, user can try cheating etc.
if (!loader.TryAddComponent(componentFromLocalFile)) {
  // Let user know that saved data failed to be loaded 
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good answer with an example of how to achieve good exception control, but fails to address when to handle and when to throw, could you expand your answer on that topic? I believe you can provide a very solid answer

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you developing and how should it be used and who use it ...

In your case which is developing game engine the best practice is to throw exceptions and forward theme to end-user(developer who use your engine to develop the game) and let the developer handle the exceptions and do proper work that he/she want.

Always try to check all possible exceptions and give useful information about the exception and thew ways to fix the mistake that raise the exception. general exception handling is for unknown and unwanted exceptions that you don't know anything about theme.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what an error is to you and what an exception is, just because your code detects that something is not as it should and it can't continue you should throw an exception.

An exception, as its name implies, happens when something exceptional and not controlled or controllable by your code happens (i.e. network connection goes down, failed to save a file because other program has it locked, a null reference you have not controlled, etc.).

Throwing exceptions tends to be costly for a computer, as it has to include a stack of what has happened, where and information on the state of the call stack, just because of that, you want to avoid exceptions as much as possible.

As it is expected that your code might not be able to run from start to finish in a set of controled conditions you take into consideration, it is a good practice to control the flow and return values that indicate that the process has not run as it was expected to, but in this case, due to some expected error which you have controlled has happened and inform that error right away.

To sum up:

- Avoid throwing exceptions for flow control of your methods, as they are costly and cause innecessary slowness on systems that consume your program.
- Only throw the exceptions you have not covered in your code or that you can't control (i.e another program the user is running grabs a file you want to use and you did not consider this possibility).
- Control as much error as you see necessary and inform the user with sensible information on what has happened in order for him to be able to solve it on his own (if he's capable to) so he can continue using and consuming your application.